# How do i search through directories and return a file to a JTextArea

Tags: java, string, swing, reader

I want to be able to go through a folder containing files and display the files that have been specified. I currently have it hard coded... Cc

```
public void searchResult(String a) throws IOException {

    FileReader inputFile;
    a = "C:\\IO\\Project.txt";
    try {
        inputFile = new FileReader(a);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            searchResult.setText(str);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SearchResults.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Please, I need something more dynamic.

Comment: This is pretty broad/vague. What is the specific problem you're encountering?

Comment: Is `String a` supposed to contain multiple files?  If so, does it have a specific format, such as a particular delimiter for separating the file names?

Answer (score 1):

> i currently have it hard coded

Do you understand how passing parameters work?

```
public void searchResult(String a) throws IOException 
{
    a = "C:\\IO\\Project.txt";

    try {
        inputFile = new FileReader(a);
```

What is the point of hardcoding the value of "a". The point of using parameters is to pass the file name as a parameter to you method.

So the code should simply be:

```
public void searchResult(String a) throws IOException 
{
    try {
        inputFile = new FileReader(a);
```

Also the following makes no sense:

```
while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    searchResult.setText(str);
```

Every time you read a new line of text you replace the previous line of text. You need to `append(...)` the text.

Or, the better solution is to just use the `read(...)` method of the `JTextArea` to load data from the file.